# How do I benchmark an algorithm implemented in D3?

Tags: algorithm, d3.js, tree, benchmarking

What will be the right way to benchmark the implementation of an algorithm compared to another in D3.
Is there any specific suite available for that?
Or any preferred way to gather data for the same dataset?

Comment: The short answer is no. Any Javascript benchmarking tools should do.

Answer (score 0):

I like using a tool called [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/). It's not specific to d3, but it's a good general way of benchmarking different algorithms against each other. To use it with d3, include this in the preparation code html:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```